# How to prevent Azure DevOps from removing zeros in string parameters

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, devops

I'm trying to pass the python version as 3.10 but i always end up getting 3.1.
is there a way to prevent it from cutting zero on my parameter?

```
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: Use Python "'${{ parameters.python_version }}'"
  inputs:
    versionSpec: "'${{ parameters.python_version }}'"
    addToPath: true
    architecture: x64
```

My last resort is to change my parameter to static value but as much as possible i want it to be dynamic.

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to prevent Azure DevOps from removing zeros in string parameters

I have defined the parameter python_version like below, and it works fine:

```
parameters:
  - name: python_version
    type: string
    default: 3.10
```

And the task like:

```
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    displayName: Use Python "'${{ parameters.python_version }}'"
    inputs:
      versionSpec: ${{ parameters.python_version }}
      addToPath: true
      architecture: x64
```

**Note**: You need remove the quotation marks on the versionSpec: `"'${{ parameters.python_version }}'"`.

And the test result is that the task will install the python with version `3.10.5`:

[image]